# How to validate a form in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to validate my data with jQuery or Javascript and send them to the server but why aren't they validated?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var name = $('#signup-name').val();
  var email = $('#signup-email').val();
  var password = $('#signup-password').val();
  var email_regex = new RegExp(/^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/i);
  var pass_regex = new RegExp(/^(?=.[0-9])(?=.[!@#$%^&])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&]{7,15}$/);

  $('#signup-form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (validate()) {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'signup',
        data: {
          email: email,
          password: password,
          name: name
        },
      });
    } else {
      return false;
    };
  });

  function validate() {
    // name cheak here
    if (name.length == "") {
      $('.nameerror').html("Name field required !");
      return false;
    } else if (name.length = < 3) {
      $('.nameerror').html("Name Should be greater than 3");
      return false;
    };
    // email cheak here

    if (email.length == "") {
      $('.emailerror').html("Email field required !");
      return false;
    } else if (!email_regex.test(email)) {
      $('.emailerror').html("Please enter correct email.");
      return false;
    };

    // password cheak here
    if (password.length == "") {
      $('.passerror').html("password field required !");
      return false;
    } else if (!pass_regex.test(password)) {#
      ('.passerror').html("Minimum eight characters, at least one letter and one number:");
      return false;
    };
  };
});
```

Comment: Any error message in console?

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error, because of the `if (name.length = < 3)`, which should of course be `if (name.length <= 3)`. But I'm assuming that's just a typo or mis-copy.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are two major issues, you were just not passing the arguments to the validate function. I have updated your code with arguments passed to the function.

Furthermore, you never returned true for any function as a result nothing would be returned. Also your if statements are split and will contradict.

I have corrected these issues, hopefully this should work!

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $('#signup-form').on('submit', function(e) {
  var name = $('#signup-name').val();
  var email = $('#signup-email').val();
  var password = $('#signup-password').val();
    e.preventDefault();
    if (validate(name, email, password)) {

      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'signup',
        data: {
          email: email,
          password: password,
          name: name
        },
      });

    } else {
      return false;
    };
  });
});


function validate(name, email, password) {
  var email_regex = new RegExp(/^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/i);
  var pass_regex = new RegExp(/^(?=.[0-9])(?=.[!@#$%^&])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&]{7,15}$/);
  // name cheak here
  if (name.length == 0) {
    $('.nameerror').html("Name field required !");
    return false;
  } else if (name.length <= 3) {
    $('.nameerror').html("Name Should be greater than 3");
    return false;
  } else if (email.length == 0) { //Check Email
    $('.emailerror').html("Email field required !");
    return false;
  } else if (!email_regex.test(email)) {
    $('.emailerror').html("Please enter correct email.");
    return false;
  } else if (password.length == 0) { // password cheak here
    $('.passerror').html("password field required !");
    return false;
  } else if (!pass_regex.test(password)) {
    ('.passerror').html("Minimum eight characters, at least one letter and one number:");
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }

};
```

Comment: The function can access those variables because they are in its global scope. Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wvkteg38/) as example.

Comment: @Cid The variables are not located within the global scope, they are within the JQuery onload function.

Comment: This is still in the **function's** global scope. Check this [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wvkteg38/1/)

Comment: I don't believe it's correct to call this "global scope" - but yes, the variables are accessible by `validate`. The issue isn't one of scope, it's that the variables hold the values when the page was first loaded (which presumably are empty), not the ones that have been entered into the form before submitting.

Comment: And even if declared outside of `$(document).ready(function() {}` while the function is in it. It's still available.

Comment: Even this works : `{ var toto = 42; } console.log(toto);` This is JS. But this doesn't work and throw an ReferenceError : `{ let toto = 42; } console.log(toto);`

Comment: I'm downvoting this since it doesn't give a solution.

Comment: @Cid I have amended my statement and corrected the code, please check the updated version.

Comment: The code isn't corrected. `} else if (name.length = < 3) {` is syntax error in example. The OP hasn't clearly checked his code nor read the console errors

Comment: @Cid I agree the OP hasn't checked is code but I have corrected it.

Comment: I also downvoted this because it doesn't fix the main issue I see (and mentioned in my own answer), which is that the `validate` function doesn't know the values of the form fields at the time of submission.

Comment: @RobinZigmond I hadn't seen that at first. I have gone ahead and corrected it.

Answer (score -1):

I believe the issue is that, although the `validate` function does indeed have access to the variables `name` etc, these are just set once when the document is first ready, and never updated. The values of the variables should be set inside the event handler for the `submit` event, before `validate` is called.